# Eslint not recognising destructing

Tags: eslint, ecmascript-2016, eslintrc, ecmascript-2017

My Eslint is not recognising that the below is valid code

```
const chai, { expect } = require('chai');
```

Can you please help me figure out which rule I need to add?

Comment: Did you maybe mean `import chai, {expect} from 'chai';`?

Comment: you are correct @Bergi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an ESLint error, that's a pure syntax error. What you have in your example translates to:

```
const chai;
const { expect } = require('chai');
```

As you can see a bit more clearly, you're essentially defining an uninitialized constant that can never be reassigned. Even the Node REPL will throw an error on that. Try the following snippet to see the error in action:

```js
const chai;
```

If what you want is *just* the `expect` method from chai, then all you need is

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
```

If you need all of chai and expect an alternative is

```
const chai = require('chai');
const { expect } = chai;
```

This would allow you to call `expect(actual).to.be.an('object');` or `chai.expect(actual).to.be.an('object');`

Comment: ah - thank you - as @bergie mention, I meant to use `import`